# Can I connect VSTS to multiple Azure Accounts using Service Connections?

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I want to deploy a web app using CI/CD from VSTS to multiple (customer) Azure accounts. So not multiple subscriptions within the same Azure account, but multiple different Azure accounts owned by customers.

The app is a managed app from the Azure Marketplace so I have full access to the resource group in which the app resides.

Is there an easy way to do this using service connections and the web deploy task or should I be using Powershell to do this and script it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that with a Managed App, for every customer deployment a resource group is created that I own and therefore shows up in my Azure account.

So from VSTS I can just use Service Connections to those resource groups, no need to connect to these other Azure accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Please create multiple Service Connections in your VSTS which used to connect to these Azure account first.
Then please create a Release pipeline with multiple environments. Then add Deploy task for every environment and choose different Azure Service Connections in different environment. Then you could deploy one app to different Azure environment through one release pipeline.

Comment: I don't think I can create Service Connections to multiple different Azure accounts. My VSTS is linked to my Azure account and I can only make service connections to that specific Azure account.